# Very Basic Question about Separation of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is a question about a fact I use all the time and know is true, but the exact reason *why* it is true is something that has never actually been explained to me.

If I have a differential operator $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\mathbb{D}f(x,y,z...,t)$ represents some arbitrary differential equation (either PDE or ODE), and I have two functions in any number of variables, let's call them $f$ and $g$, initially coupled, and I have performed some manipulation such that I arrive at:

$$\mathbb{D}f=\mathbb{D}g\tag{1}$$

It is true that these equations are totally separated and I can solve for $f$ and $g$ independently by solving the differential equations $\mathbb{D}f=0$ and $\mathbb{D}g=0$.

Why is this the case, though?

Comment: I don't understand what you're claiming, nor do I understand what you mean by "coupled" or "totally separated." Let's consider functions in one variable and take $D$ to be the ordinary derivative. If I have $f'(x) = g'(x)$ I certainly cannot solve this equation by solving $f'(x) = 0$ and $g'(x) = 0$ separately. The actual solutions take the form $f(x) = g(x) + C$.